# Rename file by its folder name

Tags: shell-script, files, rename

I have a sort of folders (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) and I have one file in every folder has the same name in all the folders (file.txt) but the size of this file is different from folder to folder.
I wanted to copy this file from every folder into a new folder (X) and give the file the same name of it is original folder.
I used this bach script to copy the files:

```
#!/bin/bash      
insub_FIM_M_1=path to a parent folder conatin all the folders (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) 

for i in $(cat $insub_FIM_M_1/FIM_1.txt); do
cp  insub_FIM_M_1/${i} <path to the new folder X >
done
```

In this code all the files will ovewrite in the new folder (X) because they have the same name inside the folders.
How can I revise this code to add the folder name to the file name so I can know the source of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your subdirectories are located in `$insub_FIM_M_1` and that the file that you want to copy is called `file.txt` in each of those subdirectories, then

```
mkdir -p result || exit 1
for pathname in "$insub_FIM_M_1"/*/file.txt; do
    cp "$pathname" "result/$( basename "$( dirname "$pathname" )" )_file.txt"
done
```

would copy these files to the `result` directory in the current directory while renaming each file according to the directory that they are located in.

Answer (score 3):

In the special case where the directory is the parent directory you can use rename/prename[1] from the parent directory to move the files to that parent directory:

```
rename -n 's:/:-:g' */file.txt
```

(`-n` is for dry runs, remove it or replace by `-v` for actual execution)

If the `.txt` files are several levels deep (or at an unknown depth), you can use the globstar option:

```
shopt -s globstar  # makes '**' match any levels of directories
rename -n 's:/:-:g' **/*.txt
```

[1] The command is `rename` on Debian/Ubuntu and derivatives, and `prename` on Redhat/Fedora and derivatives

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked:

```
 #!/bin/bash   
insub_FIM_M_1=path to a parent folder conatin all the folders (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H) 
out=path 
for i in $(cat $insub_FIM_M_1/FIM_1.txt); do
cp  insub_FIM_M_1/file.txt ${path}/${i}.txt
done
```

Comment: Having a `#!` in the middle of the code makes no sense. The two characters `#!` needs to be first ones in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you're using `cat FIM_1.txt` as this is a file you've not told us about. This code will copy `file.txt` from each of a set of folders and place in in the directory `X` named as the folder from which it came.

```
cd "$insub_FIM_M_1"
for DIR in *
do
    test -d "$DIR" -a -f "$DIR/file.txt" || continue
    mv -f "$DIR/file.txt" "/path/to/X/$DIR"
done
```

Comment: Why not loop over `*/file.txt`?

Comment: @Kusalananda no particular reason. Maybe because two years ago I didn't think of using `"${path%/file.txt}"` or equivalent expresssions?